# Time delay estimate and sampling frequency

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation, time-frequency, compressive-sensing

This is an extention to my other [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14735/time-delay-estimation-using-ultrasound). My sampling frequency is only about 2x my tone frequency. I want to estimate time delay of arrival using this signal. I am generating the tone signal so I know its properties. Can I use compressed sensing to reconstruct my tone wave received by the sensors and get a good time delay estimate? An answer with some matlab code would be brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine has investigated time delay estimation using compressed sensing in this paper: http://vbn.aau.dk/en/publications/compressive-parameter-estimation-for-sparse-translationinvariant-signals-using-polar-interpolation(56d35506-d4ae-4296-9a36-7ec95b1160c7).html
You can find the accompanying Matlab code here: http://www.sparsesampling.com/cpe/

Answer (score 1):

You should try to measure the phase of the signals, since so you can average out errors. Phase difference is proportional to time delay, but wraps.